# Select with 2 conditions

Tags: mysql, vb.net

can you please help me to fix the following code:

The code is trying to get data according to the 2 conditions:

1. Select data when a checkbox and a value form a drop down list is checked
2. Select data when only a checkbox is checked ( this one is working fine so I am not going to list it)

If I select multiple check boxes the values are shown properly but when I try to add the second condition no values are shown.

Date looks like this `DD/MM/YY`

I am using **vb** and **mysql(DB)**

```
If c1check AndAlso ComboBox2.SelectedItem > 0 Then

searchQuery = "Select USERS_NUMBER FROM DB WHERE EXPIRATION_DATE LIKE '%" _
   & String.Join("%'and EXPIRATION_DATE LIKE " + "'%", myList) _
   & + "%' AND RIGHT(EXPIRATION_DATE, 3) = '%" & Trim(ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString) & "'"
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as [tag:vba]?

Comment: You also should be using proper DATETIME for your date column, not strings, and then you can just use `BETWEEN` to find the dates you want. Your string concatenation is wrong also, as is your SQL syntax, and you're leaving yourself wide open for SQL injection by directly concatenating user input. It's pretty difficult to tell you how to correct those things based on the limited amount of information you've provided. It would help if we had sample data, the input you're using, and the output you want to get from that query.

Comment: What does one date being LIKE another date mean to you? Are they the same year? same month? same day? same day of the week?

Comment: Add a line of code directly after the code you posted and put `Debug.Print(searchQuery)`  Let us know what the Immediate window shows.

Comment: What is some sample data in you myList array. I assume the array is of type String.